# Searching for Excel event BEFORE BOOK OPEN or other solution

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio, events, event-handling

I am working on an Excel COM-Addin, which shall open predefined Excel templates/files. To make sure that the excel templates can only be used in combination with the addin, I want to password protect certain files. The tricky part is to find or define a BEFORE OPEN WORKBOOK - event. Aim is to hand over the password and open the file without getting a promt window.

I have tried and failed with the following events:

1.

```
EventDel_BookOpen = New Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(AddressOf OpenWorkbook)
AddHandler xlApp.WorkbookOpen, EventDel_BookOpen

Private Sub OpenWorkbook(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook)
    If wb.HasPassword Then
        wb.Password = "test"
    End If
End Sub
```

The event is triggering after the prompt window popping up.

2.

```
EventDel_WBookOpen = New Excel.WorkbookEvents_OpenEventHandler(AddressOf WBOpenWorkbook)
AddHandler xlBook.Open, EventDel_WBookOpen

Private Sub WBOpenWorkbook()
    If xlBook.HasPassword Then
        wb.Password = "test"
    End If
End Sub
```

This event is not triggering at all.

Please, let me know, if you have any good ideas to solve my problem.

Many thanks in advance,

Rainer

Comment: Can you use the Excel VBA `WorkBooks.Open` method? This allows you to include a password required to open a workbook.

Comment: Have a look at the 2nd try. This should be basically the `Workbook.Open` method you are suggesting ... but it is unfortunately not working ;o(

Comment: What about trying to force Password opening with your password and check the error rose by Excel?

Comment: Hello JMax, I do not fully understand your approach. How can I tell the Excel-App always to open with a given password? Isn't this also related to an Excel-event like 'Excel.WorkbookEvents_OpenEventHandler`?

Comment: In place of password-protecting the workbook, you could instead make all but one sheet "very hidden", and protect the workbook structure with a password.  Then you can deal with the workbook *after* it's already open, instead of having to divert the Open event.

Comment: I faced a similar problem in a past project. First I tried the same method that @TimWilliams suggested. However, I felt that it was too easy for someone to open the workbook and the VBA editor and unhide a very hidden worksheet and then modify the password. So I turned to OpenXML - my addin/project would dynamically generate a unique password and insert it into the target workbook (without opening it via Excel). I could then check if the password matched when the workbook opened - if it did not, then the workbook would immediately close with a message stating that it must be opened with my app

Comment: Hello Tim, thank you for your suggestion. I will try that solution. Hopefully it will have no bad effect on the usability!

Comment: Hello rwisch45, do you have any code example? Your idea sounds interesting, but I am not that familar with OpenXML. Many thanks!